# Responsive site shown in full width on phone (but not on emulated phone)

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design

This is a responsive theme: http://bsetec.com/demoprojects/magento/free_templates/index.php/?___store=electronics_english

If you view the site in an emulated mobile browser, the narrow version is shown (which is the desired behaviour).
http://transmog.net/iphone-simulator/mobile-web-browser-emulator.php?u=http://bsetec.com/demoprojects/magento/free_templates/index.php/?___store=electronics_english

But if I view it on an actual mobile device, I see the desktop version.

What do I have to change to see the narrow layout on my phone?[image: bad on real phone and good on emulated phone]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

to the head of your page, I think that's the source of your troubles.

Without this, smartphones will typically scale the page to fit, which isn't what you want with a responsive site.

Good luck!